# JAVA - Split e Arrays

Tags: java

Olá,

Preciso ler várias strings, dividi-lás em partes e alocar em arrays.

O problema é que o meu código até armazena os pedaços da string nas variáveis, mas eu preciso ler várias peças, por isso preciso transformar esses atributos em arrays.

Tenho quatro atributos: Tipo, que recebe char, Cor, recendo String, e X e Y que recebem int.

Um exemplo de entrada para esse código é: C Branco 2 2.

```
public void inserirPeças() throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        System.out.println("Insira as peças: ");
        String str = input.readLine(); // le a linha inteira
        String[] tokens = str.split(" "); // pega os tokens separadamente

        tipo = tokens[0].charAt(0); // le o tipo
        cor = tokens[1]; // le a cor
        x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); // x
        y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]); // y
    }   
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para declarar os atributos como arrays use essas instruções:

```
char[] tipo;
String[] cor;
int[] x;
int[] y;
```

E quando você souber o tamanho delas (supondo que seja `num`), inicialize-as:

```java
public void inserirPeças() throws IOException {

    // Inicializando as arrays
    tipo = new char[num];
    cor = new String[num];
    x = new int[num];
    y = new int[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insira as peças: ");
        String str = input.readLine();
        String[] tokens = str.split(" ");

        // Não se esqueça do índice das arrays
        tipo[i] = tokens[0].charAt(0);
        cor[i] = tokens[1];
        x[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        y[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
    }   
}
```